# How can I make a tree node to be root based on its value recursively?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

given 2 arrays `C[],D[]` c is cities d is city  value as:

```
  C[0] = 1    D[0] = 6
C[1] = 3    D[1] = 2
C[2] = 0    D[2] = 7
C[3] = 3    D[3] = 5
C[4] = 2    D[4] = 6
C[5] = 4    D[5] = 5
C[6] = 4    D[6] = 2
```

the city c[0]=1 that city # 0 linked with city # 1 and city 0's value=6,
and city c[1]=3 that city # 1 linked with city # 3 and city 1's value=2,
and so on i represent them in binary tree but how can i make the city with the greatest value is the root with keeping relations as i rotate the tree.

the target is count number of cities with largest values and connected only this 
the code:

```
class BinaryTree {

    Node root;

    public void addNode(int toCity, int name, int atractiveness) {



        Node newNode = new Node(toCity, name, atractiveness);



        if (root == null) {

            root = newNode;

        } else {


            Node focusNode = root;



            Node parent;

            while (true) {



                parent = focusNode;



                if (toCity < focusNode.toCity) {



                    focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;



                    if (focusNode == null) {



                                parent.leftChild = newNode;


                        return; 

                    }

                } else { 

                    focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;



                    if (focusNode == null) {



                        parent.rightChild = newNode;
                        return; // All Done

                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }




    public void preorderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {
                int totalNumOfCities=0;
                int totalAtractivness=0;
        if (focusNode != null) {

            System.out.println(focusNode);

            preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);
            preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);

        }

    }



    public Node findNode(int name) {



        Node focusNode = root;

        while (focusNode.name != name) {



            if (name < focusNode.name) {



                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;

            } else {



                focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;

            }



            if (focusNode == null)
                return null;

        }

        return focusNode;

    }

}


public int solution(int K, int[] C, int[] D){

BinaryTree theTree = new BinaryTree();

for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
    theTree.addNode(C[i], i,D[i]);

}
theTree.preorderTraverseTree(theTree.root);
return 0;
}


}
```

Comment: You may want to think about using a B-Tree design for this instead of as I assume you are trying to use a form of BST.

Comment: I think @DavidColer means a B+ tree. Also, do you know all the nodes beforehand? if so, all you have to do is sort the list of D and find the greatest value to use as root.

Comment: i want to return the max number of cities based on its value but must be connected each other may so i want to get the max D value of subtree on run time which algorithm should i use BST or B-Tree?

Comment: looks like your links form a bipartite graph.